# Google app is blocked while it's being verified in production

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console

Google app in `production` mode is blocked for use by users.

> This app is blocked
> This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

[image]

It works fine when I switch back to `testing` mode. Currently, it's verification status is pending due to the sensitive scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events`

What I've gathered from [the docs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?authuser=2) is that certain number of users should still be able to connect to oauth (after the unverified app warning though) but that's not the case here.

[image]

Did I miss something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a catch 22 situation. In order to apply for verification your app needs to be set to production.  Then you can apply for verification.

Once your app has been verified it will then work.

Test users only work while your app is in testing mode.   Consider having two projects one for development and another for production.

Comment: But I can't use test project on prod url. Verification process requires prod project on the prod url.

Comment: Then you need to wait until its verified

Answer (score 0):

It seem like Google unblocked it after 2-3 days (my app is still under verification though)

[image]

#### Update 2:

It's in blocked state again. Not sure what's going on with Google.

[image]